# AngularJS get formatted date in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have following text input filled by model value in timestamp:

```
<input type="datetime" ng-model="workerDetail.dateOfBirth"  class="form-control" id="date_of_birth" />
```

It displays value in input as given timestamp.

I would like to convert value which is visible in input into formatted date (YYYY/MM/DD), but in model should be always as timestamp.

I tried to do it by this way:

```
{{workerDetail.dateOfBirth | date:'MMM'}}
```

But without luck.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can try a filter

HTML

```
<input type="datetime" ng-model="mydateOfBirth"  class="form-control" id="date_of_birth" />
```

Controller JS

```
$scope.$watch('mydateOfBirth', function (newValue) {
    $scope.workerDetail.dateOfBirth = $filter('date')(newValue, 'yyyy/MM/dd'); 
});

$scope.$watch('workerDetail.dateOfBirth', function (newValue) {
    $scope.mydateOfBirth = $filter('date')(newValue, 'yyyy/MM/dd'); 
});
```

Comment: In fact, this answer caused me a trouble in a more sophisticated example, so I went for Sergio Toledo's one and everything got fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can also specify a timezone like this:

```
$scope.$watch('workerDetail.dateOfBirth', function (newDate) {
    $scope.workerDetail.dateOfBirth = $filter('date')(newDate, 'HH:mm', 'UTC'); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This code to Get a date Only (dd/mm/yyyy)

html

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
<input type="date" name="dob" class="input-lg form-group" ng-model='dob'>
</div>
```

Angularjs

```
app.controller('myctrl',function($scope, $http,$window,$filter) {
$scope.sent=function(){
    $scope.date = $filter("date")($scope.dob, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
    alert($scope.date);
}})
```