# Angularjs fullDate filter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, uidatepicker, angular-ui-datepicker

I'm getting following error on using fullDate filter inside my html:

> Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'publisherForm.dt |
>   date:'fullDate'' is non-assignable. Element:

**Here is my jade code:**

datepicker.well.well-sm(ng-model="publisherForm.dt", show-weeks="false", min-date="minDate")

input.form-control(type="text", ng-model=" publisherForm.dt | date:'fullDate' ", readonly='')

what I'm trying is show the selected date from ui-datepicker to user in another input field. Since I want to show only date, I'm using fullDate filter but in console I'm getting above mentioned error.

Any idea what can be the possible reason ?

Comment: can't use filters in `ng-model`. it's expression has to resolve to a scope variable. Will need to create directive to parse the $viewModel

Comment: And how exactly can I do that ?

Comment: Shouldn't be hard to find numerous solutions in posts here and in google tutorials, posts etc

Comment: Is there any other simple way of accomplishing this task ? I just need to show a value in the input box based on some $scope variable with a filter ? Is there anyway to achieve this without making it complicated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On searching through existing threads on SO, I found following threads which helped me to solve my problem:

[Using angularjs filter in input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343068/using-angularjs-filter-in-input-element)
[How to format a date using ng-model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474555/how-to-format-a-date-using-ng-model)
[AngularJS get formatted date in ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486696/angularjs-get-formatted-date-in-ng-model)

Finally made following lines of code change and it started working fine for me:

> ```
> $scope.$watch('publisherForm.dt', function(newVal){
>   $scope.publisherForm.formattedDate = $filter('date')($scope.publisherForm.dt, 'fullDate');
> });
> ```

If there is anyone who can suggest a better solution is always welcome.

Thanks