# Expected to be a date angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, date

I'm pulling this JSON from the mongodb, and I have a date field which have the type as DATE.

I want be able to change the date if needed in a interface, for this I need a input type date field with the attribute ng-model="event.date", just like this:

```
<input class="tables__sidebar-input" type="date" ng-model='event.date'>
```

This is throwing an error:

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2015-09-03T00:00:00.000Z` to be a date
```

I found the reason for the error and fixed it. I found this directive which SHOULD fix the error:

```
angular.module('adminApp')
  .directive("myModelFilter", ["$filter", function($filter) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
        ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          //convert data from view format to model format

          // Grab the parameters
          var params = scope.$eval(attrs.myModelFilter);

          // Filter with the parameters passed
          return $filter(params.filter)(data, params.expr, params.comp);

        });

        ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
          //convert data from model format to view format
          // Grab the parameters
          var params = scope.$eval(attrs.myModelFilter);

          // Filter with the parameters passed
          return $filter(params.filter)(data, params.expr, params.comp);
        });
      }
    };
  }])
```

To use, simply add `my-model-filter="{filter:'date', expr:'yyyy-MM-dd'}"` in the input field, which I did:

```
<input class="tables__sidebar-input" type="date" ng-model='event.date' my-model-filter="{filter:'date', expr:'yyyy-MM-dd'}">
```

But now is throwing the same error with the valid format:

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2015-09-02` to be a date
```

What's missing here?

I'm pulling the data from a model service by a controller:

retrieve action:

```
retrieve: function() {
    var that = this;

    this.EventModel.Model.find()
        .then(function(result) {
            that.$scope.events = result;
        });
}
```

Please guys, help me! I already read every stackoverflow answer, every post blog and I cant figure out how to fix it.

I don't want use a mask with the type text, I want use type="date" which is the right format.

Comment: Have you looked into this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486696/angularjs-get-formatted-date-in-ng-model?rq=1  It doesn't look like you need a new directive, just use a simple $filter expression.

Comment: By the structure that i'm using i cant use in controller, i need a filter for solve the problem..

Comment: Could you help me? i can give 100 of my points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use. I delete all existings $formatters, $parsers with .splice, since I don't need that, but you may want to keep those.

How to use on directive is like `type="date" as-date`

```
angular.module('someApp')
    .directive('asDate', function () {
    return {
        require: '^ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$formatters.splice(0, ctrl.$formatters.length);
            ctrl.$parsers.splice(0, ctrl.$parsers.length);
            ctrl.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
                if (!modelValue) {
                    return;
                }
                return new Date(modelValue);
            });
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (modelValue) {
                return modelValue;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: i'm going to try, give me a sec.

Comment: YOU, do you know why this erro -> The specified value 'Wed Sep 02 2015 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)' does not conform to the required format, 'yyyy-MM-dd'. ?

Comment: 1. Is it a browser warning or angular error? 2. may be try `new Date(modelValue);` to `new Date(modelValue).toISOString().slice(0,10);` in $formatters OR `return modelValue` to `return new Date(modelValue).toISOString().slice(0,10);` in $parsers

Comment: @amanda, its ok. no need. I had frustration too when I upgrade to angular 1.4. behavior changed since angular 1.3 I think, which was no problem with angular 1.2. JSON don't have native `Date` format, and angular want it native `Date` format, HTML5 date field want it as `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: angular have some serious problems i think, there are somethings that should naturally work, this is just one..

Comment: In this jquery asks for format yyyy-MM-dd and in tern gets a string in Wed Apr 20 2016 19:24:05 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) format. I suggest one more change to make this work smoothly . Replace the return statement with 
var val = filter('date')(new Date(modelValue),'yyyy-MM-dd');
return val;