# Format date value in material design to remove time

Tags: angular-material

I have the following input on my form:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex>
    <label>Install Date</label>
    <input type="text" date="yyyy-MM-dd" ng-model="selectedCompanyDetail.InstallDate" disabled>
</md-input-container>
```

As you can probably tell, I want the date displayed with this format `yyyy-MM-dd`. However, what I am getting is this: `1993-01-01T00:00:00`.

It looks correct if I do this:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex>
    <label>Install Date</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selectedCompanyDetail.InstallDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd':'UTC'" disabled>
</md-input-container>
```

But, I get this error in the developer tools:

> angular.js:13307 Error: [ngModel:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.2/ngModel/nonassign?p0=selectedCompanyDetail.InstallDate%20%7CNaNate%3A'yyyy-MM-dd'%3A'UTC'&p1=%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20date%3D%22yyyy-MM-dd%22%20ng-model%3D%selectedCompanyDetail.InstallDate%20%7C%date%3A'yyyy-MM-dd'%3A'UTC'%22%20disabled%3D%22%22%class%3D%22ng-pristine%20ng-untouched%20ng-valid%22%3E
>       at Error (native)
>       at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.min.js:6:421

I can still use the view, but every date field has this same error.

I have many date fields and don't want to add a filter to each one as suggested here: [AngularJS get formatted date in ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486696/angularjs-get-formatted-date-in-ng-model)

There has to be a native way to format a date input like a date without the time.

Suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Did you looked into using the [mdDateLocaleProvider](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDateLocaleProvider) ?

Comment: @steur36, this still uses moment.js to format the date. How can angular not have a native way to do this?

Comment: You are using `md-datepicker` right ?

Comment: In this particular view, no. Users cannot edit the values. The only reason it is an input is for consistency in appearance. However, md-datepicker has another issue where it shows a date different than the actual date (e.g. it shows 4/10/2016 when the db value is 4/11/2016).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package to handle any kind of date and time manipulation. https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

I use it like this.

```
selectedCompanyDetail.InstallDateNewFormat = moment(selectedCompanyDetail.InstallDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

You must another model to store this new date since `md-datepicker` only allows `data` javascript object. while this format returns plain text(string).

Comment: I was trying to avoid loading another package. I can use a filter to achieve the same result, but am hoping there is a straightforward approach that doesn't require additional files.